# How to use Angular scope with a service request and a directive

Tags: angularjs, service, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that queries a service, like so:

```
app.controller('CandListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cand',
  function ($scope, Cand) {

    Cand.query(function(data) {
      //data processing can happen here
      $scope.candidates = data;
    });

  }]);
```

My service queries a Google sheet:

```
var sheetServices = angular.module('candServices', []);

    sheetServices.factory('Cand', ['$rootScope',
      function($rootScope){
        return {
          query: function(callback) {
            Tabletop.init({
              key: '{{my key}}',
              simpleSheet: true,
              parseNumbers: true,
              callback: function(data, tabletop) {
                if(callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {
                  $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback(data);
                  });
                }
              }
            });
          }
        };
      }]);
```

My directive:

```
app.directive('timeline', function () {

  return function (scope, element, attrs) {

      var events = scope.candidates;
      console.log(events); //undefined
 }
})
```

I use the timeline directive in route partial view:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/cand-list.html',
        controller: 'CandListCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

cand-list.html:

```
<div id="timeLine"><div timeline ng-style="myStyle"></div></div>
```

My issue is that I cannot access $scope.candidates from within my directives because it is scoped to the query function.

I could of course create a closure that draws the variable value out of the function. But that seems un-Angular.

What is the best way forward?

Comment: Where is your directive code ?

Comment: Updated with directive code

Comment: Can you show the html where you use `timeline`?

Comment: More code added to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to communicate b/w directive and controller
First you need to create a seperate scope of the directive and allow it to access data from the controller scope by using  `'=','@'` etc.

Suppose your html is this:

```
<div>
   <timeline candidates="candidates"></timeline>
</div>
```

And your javascript:

```
app.directive('timeline', function () {

  return {
    scope:{
      candidates:"="
    },

    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
     scope.$watch('candidates', function() { 
              var events = scope.candidates; 
              console.log(events); 
         }) 
    }
  }
})
```

Good [Example](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/)
Read more about directives on the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: This still isn't working for me. Trying iterations. But you're right that I have a lot to learn. My 2nd week on Angular.

Comment: The div is representing the controller part.Have you added the controller on the top of directive ?

Comment: Yes the controller is attached to divs parent to the directive. Could it be the way the rootscope is modified by the service?

Comment: events is still undefined

Comment: What's odd is if i console.log(scope), I can see "candidates" as a property. But scope.candidates logs undefined..

Comment: It is happening because there is no data intialy in scope.candidate until the response is send to the controller by service i guess you need to use $watch on the candidate variable and wait for the data to respond.

Comment: Added to the directive, this works: scope.$watch('candidates', function() {
        var events = scope.candidates;
        console.log(events);
      })

Comment: yup $watch wiil listen for the change in value of candidates.

Comment: If you update I'll accept. Do you think this is a good implementation?

Comment: Yes it's the perfect one :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event emitter:

```
Cand.query(function(data) {
  // data processing can happen here
  $scope.candidates = data;
  // tell everyone that data is loaded
  $scope.$root.$broadcast('Cand.loaded', data);
});
```

And in your directive:

```
app.directive('timeline', function () {
  return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$on('Cand.loaded', function(e, data) {
       var events = data;
       console.log(events); //defined
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: This should not be used because $broadcasting a event is heavy task run digest cycle of angular and check for each binding which may lead to lack in performance in long run.

Comment: If it is in the angular context it will not run a new digect cycle. Your solution also requires a digest cycle for the $watch to be executed, the performance impact is the same. Mine is actually more performant as the broadcast will likely be sent only once (when the data is get), while your $watch will be triggered on every digest cycle... However if the directive is suppoed to behave according to candidates it is cleaner to not rely on events, so it is great too and I think it's worth for OP to know both alternatives.